# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou aprendendo a fazer `App` utilizando o `Xamarin 2017`, e quando tento fazer a conexão com a base de dados que criei via `SQLite`, a aplicação apresenta esse erro:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Como eu poderia arrumar isso?

O erro se dá nesse ponto:

```
public UsuarioDataAccess()
{
    database = DependencyService
            .Get<IDatabaseConnection>()
            .ConexaoDatabase();
    database.CreateTable<Usuario>();
```

Comment: é a variável `database` aonde dá esse erro?

Comment: Exatamente. Nao sei o que fazer...

Comment: Tem que verificar com um debug porque essa linha `DependencyService            .Get<IDatabaseConnection>().ConexaoDatabase();` não está retornando uma conexão de banco, já tentou fazer isso ... ???

Comment: Ele só da problema quando faço isso.. e é essa a mensagem que aparece quando eu dou o debug

Comment: Você criou a classe que implementa a interface IDatabaseConnection?

Answer (score 0):

O objetivo do `DependencyService` é facilitar a criação de APP que acesse API's específicas de cada plataforma (Android, IOS, Windows Mobile, etc).

Se o estudo que você estiver fazendo não necessitar dessa portabilidade, você poderá instanciar direto o objeto da classe que implementa `IDatabaseConnection` sem usar `DependencyService`.

```
database = (new CLASSE_QUE_IMPLEMENTA_IDatabaseConnection()).ConexaoDatabase();
database.CreateTable<Usuario>();
```

Agora, se você for usar `DependencyService`, será necessário implementar 3 coisas em seu projeto:

**1) Definir a `interface`**

```
public interface IDatabaseConnection
{
    MinhaClasseConexao ConexaoDatabase(); 
}
```

**2) Criar a classe que implemente a `interface`**

```
public class DatabaseConnectionImplementacao : IDatabaseConnection
{ 
   // implementar código da classe
}
```

**3) Registrar a classe que implementa a `interface`;**

```
//registrar a classe usando um atributo do namespace da classe 
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (DatabaseConnectionImplementacao ))]
namespace MeuApp.Android 
{
   public class DatabaseConnectionImplementacao : IDatabaseConnection
   { 
      // implementar código da classe
   }
}
```

Veja: [Introduction to DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/)

Pela descrição do seu problema, você deve ter feito o primeiro passo mas não implementou os outros dois.